# Why the pressence of Expression itself among method parameters makes method slow in C#

Tags: c#, performance, lambda, expression, compiler-optimization

Please, consider to methods:

```
    private void FastMethod(string param)
    {
    }

    private void SlowMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
    }
```

And the following test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            this.FastMethod("TestContext");
        }

        TestContext.WriteLine("Fast time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        stopwatch.Restart();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            this.SlowMethod(() => this.TestContext);
        }

        TestContext.WriteLine("Slow time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

And the output is:

> Fast time: 4
>
> Slow time: 2249

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qSTW.png

I know it's per 1 million calls, so this may not look like a serious performance issue.

But I want to have some logic based on expressions inside property setters and they are going to be invoke fairly often + I am just curious.

Is there any space for optimization here?  ( I cannot get rid of `Expression` in method parameters, basically I need to do some syntax tree parsing. The funny thing is that parsing itself is fast enough).

Comment: Looks like there may be some implicit conversions and/or boxing going on, have you tried to modify the `SlowMethod` test to use a defined `Expression` or even `Func<T>` without using anonymous methods inside the function call? Also the first method can mostly be optimized away, which is why its unbelievably fast, the time is mostly the string concatenation inside `WriteLine` and retrieving the time from the stopwatch..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C# compiler is generating the expression tree on your behalf for each and every iteration the method is called. It is not free.

If you look at the compiled IL --you can see what is going behind the scenes.There are lot of allocation involved there.

You can confirm this by initializing the expression tree outside the loop.

```
Expression<Func<TestContext>> parameter = () => this.TestContext;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    this.SlowMethod(parameter);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Fast time: 3
Slow time: 3
```